# low image quality when draw text on it ( C# )

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am going to create a bitmap image and draw a text but the quality of the image for printing purpose is low and the pixels are visible and are not like when i print through microsoft word.

For few reasons I don't want to use PrintDocument.

Anti Aliasing did not help me too, I have tried all image type ( Tif, bmp, png )

The following is part of the code that we use.

```
MyBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(GetMaxWidthOfReport(), MyActualPageSizeInfo.Height);

Mygraphics =System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(MyBitmap);

Mygraphics.TextContrast = 4;
Mygraphics.PageUnit = System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Display; 
Mygraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; 
Mygraphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality; 
Mygraphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver; 
Mygraphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality; 
Mygraphics.InterpolationMode =     System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear; 

Mygraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
```

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: Printing text directly using the Graphics device context will give you better quality than printing it to an image first.  Why do you want to draw to an image first instead of drawing directly to the Graphics for a page?

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following approach:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(300, 100, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText(g, 
        @"low image quality when draw text on it", Font, new Point(10, 10), Color.Black);
}
```